# Is it possible to obtain WiFi mobile phone's signal strength on router side via .NET?

Tags: .net, wifi, triangulation, signal-strength

Let's assume this network layout: 1 router, 1 laptop(as server), 1 mobile phone. 
[image]

Laptop and mobile phone are connected to the router via WiFi.

**Question 1**: Is it possible(using .NET or Java) from laptop side to get dB or dBm(signal strength) values for this mobile phone without any action on the mobile phone side(besides connection to the wifi)? Or is it only possible if router manufacturer provides SDK?

**Question 2**: Does router measures mobile phone's signal strength?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, we cannot obtain signal level on the device without having any information from it. And it's not software that constraints us but physics.

Longer one is:
Signal level is a function of router emitting power, antenna adjustment, device location (in router's coordinate system) and environment conditions (e.g. rain or other networks' interference).

While you might get router's emitting power from router SW, it's very unlikely to get antenna (antennas?) adjustment, virtually impossible to get device location (you would need some kind of GPS - like interface, which is, I believe, pretty much special) and totally impossible to get weather conditions.

Good news is that device measures signal level anyway it anyway, so if you have anything installed on it, it is accessible without problem. For example, here is some reference for Android:

http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiWatchdogStateMachine.java#103

Comment: If mobile phone is connected to the router, they sometimes send some packets between each other, does router does measure signal strength from connected phone?

Comment: router is not able to measure signal strenght - it is possible only on device. What could be done, is that signal level might be sent to router at some intervals to decide about possible handovers, but I am not aware of such mechanism in WiFi networks. But I'm not 100% sure if that's the case

Comment: I heard about malls spying on clients(their routs) using wifi positioning. So they had to install software on mall's clients side first?

Comment: Let us continue talk on the chat if you have 10 mins: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68185/wifi-triangulation

Comment: That might be a little different story - on router you may measure level of signal that user has sent (it's different from signal level that user receives) - if you measure at 3 points, you can guess (more or less) where the user is (assuming some constant environment - you can do it in a mall). Though I cannot say for sure, as I am not really familiar with techniques used by malls.